# CNN model why the data is too large?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, training-data

[image: the error message]

[image: the model structure]

- use keras and tensorflow backend
- use CPU only , memory 128GB
- input data has the shape (45,1024,1024)
- the model has only one convolution , one (2,2) max pooling
- a 1024 *1024 fully connected.

I got this error message:

> Invalid argument: Shape [4194304,1048576] is too large (more than
>   1099511627776 entries)

note that:

```
4194304 = 2048 * 2048
1048576 = 1024 * 1024
```

How did keras compute this shape? why is it too large?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shape `[4194304, 1048576]` is computed as follows:

Applying 16 convolutions of size `[3, 3]` with the `same` border mode to the inputs of size `[1024, 1024, 3]` gives us output of size `[1024, 1024, 16]`. After max pooling of size 2 it becomes `[512, 512, 16]` which when flattened is `512 * 512 * 16 = 4194304`. `1048576` comes from `1024 * 1024` as you specified in the `Dense` layer constructor.

I think you should reconsider the architecture of you model. You can use inputs of smaller size, add several pooling layers, reduce dimensionality applying `1 x 1` convolutions. And I doubt that `1024 * 1024` is a reasonable number of nodes in a fully connected layer.